# Difference between System.copy and StrUtils.MidStr

Tags: delphi

Delphi has functions `System.copy` and `StrUtils.MidStr` that both return a substring from within a `string`. Is there a difference between these two functions?

If so, what is the difference? And when should I use each one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed, there is no difference: `MidStr()` uses `Copy()`. For strings that is, because `Copy()` can also be used for arrays, for which `MidStr()` is not suited.

*(Personally, I think that some of the routines published by `StrUtils` unit are made for those who were comfortable with VB.)*

Comment: Out of the two, I think MidStr is more descriptive of what it does than 'Copy'. Although I'd say 'SubString' is better than either.